# VBA incorrectly entering range as series name

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I'm trying to create a dynamic graph in VBA in Excel. Unfortunately, when I generate the graph the values that are meant for the y axis are ending up as the series name. [Here's the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubtCU.png). I'm an extremely new VBA user, so I'm sure I am just overlooking a very basic error. Here is my code.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

'Find the last non-blank cell in column G and H
Range("G3:H500").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
lastrow = ActiveCell.Row - 1

'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

MsgBox "Last Row: " & lastrow & vbNewLine & _
        "" & Columns(lCol).Address(False, False)

Set rng = Range("G3:H300" & lastrow)
Set xrang = Range("F3:F300" & lastrow)

rng.Select

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
    "c:\users\name\appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\brand_line_chart.crtx" _
    )
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("G3:H300" & lastrow)
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("F3:F300" & lastrow)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line                                       ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("F3:F300" & lastrow).        Also since you are getting the lastrow data , change the ("G3:H300" & lastrow) to ("G3:H" & lastrow). Do this everywhere you have set range